# Restrict the url_suffix in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am using codeigniter 2.1.4 and I have set `$config['url_suffix'] = ".html";`

It's working fine with out any trouble. But I found out that if I use `redirect();` function will always add `url_suffix` on the landing page url. eg: **site.com/login/success.html**.

My question is there anyway to exclude the `url_suffix` while using the `redirect()` function? or is there anyway to add .html without setting `url_suffix` in codeigniter, may be some hack in .htaccess??

I tried to add

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

in the project htaccess file, but once i unset the url_suffix variable the framework throws 404 error. Any work around?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could leave the `url_suffix` config blank `$config['url_suffix'] = '';` and define specific routes to add `.html` suffix to some cases.

For instance, for the blog posts:

In `routes.php` *(which is located at `application/config/` by default)*:

```php
$route['blog/(.+)\.html'] = "posts/view_post/$1";
/*                           ^     ^         ^
                             |     |         |
                Controller ---   Method      --- Post SEO url or ID
*/
```