# codeigneiter url issue with html and without html > I have added suffix also

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

html and without .html working on Codeigniter. I want only URL with .html should work.

**For e.g:** abc.com/one.html

this should be work and

abc.com/one shouldn't work.

I need only one URL should work due to SEO. If both URL will work it will affect the SEO due to duplicate content

Hi Have added suffix in the config file

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726776/codeigniter-url-suffix-html-automatically-for-all-url

Comment: my question is different and you are giving different answer

Comment: try to change htaccess file
Source -: https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-

Comment: @Usira : Is there other method  ? so without .html url won't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356392/restrict-the-url-suffix-in-codeigniter maybe this will help

Comment: https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-1540.html and this too

Comment: Where did you read that having .html is better than just using the standard non .html? Unless you have an existing site that used .html and it's been converted to CI controller/method it should have no affect. Why would Google even try using /one as opposed to /one.html unless you have both in your links. Are you 100% sure this is a real issue?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw : my previous site has .html extension so for new one i have to use .html extension. My competitor they try to access my site both ways . Thats why i am asking this